# Unable to create array of objects in angularjs in foreach loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am developing web application in angularjs. I have one foreach loop to loop through scope object. Below is my js code.

```
$scope.details = [];
$scope.apply = function() {
    angular.forEach($scope.screenMap, function(value, key) {
        //$scope.details.push(value.scrn_id, value.Read, value.Write);
        $scope.details.push("ID", value.scrn_id);
        $scope.details.push("Read", value.Read);
        $scope.details.push("Write", value.Write);
    });
    console.log($scope.details);
}
```

After looping I get total 18 entries for 3 iterations.

What I am expecting is

```
  ID:1  Read:True  Write: False
  ID:2  Read:False  Write: True
  ID:3  Read:True  Write: False
  ID:4  Read:False  Write: True
```

may I know how can I get array in above format?

Comment: *Unable to create array of obejcts in angularjs in foreach loop*, but you didn't create an object. You are making an array of properties. Combine the properties in an object and then push.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

push it as an object

```
$scope.details = [];
        $scope.apply = function () {
            angular.forEach($scope.screenMap, function (value, key) {

                $scope.details.push({"ID": value.scrn_id,
                                    "Read": value.Read,
                                    "Write": value.Write});
            });
            console.log($scope.details);
        }
```

Comment: @NiranjanGodbole You should consider who answered first while accepting answers. :(

Answer (score 2):

You have to push to the array the values as an object to achieve this.

```
$scope.details = [];
        $scope.apply = function () {
            angular.forEach($scope.screenMap, function (value, key) {
                //$scope.details.push(value.scrn_id, value.Read, value.Write);
                $scope.details.push({"ID":value.scrn_id,"Read":value.Read,"Write":value.Write});
            });
            console.log($scope.details);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
$scope.details = [];
$scope.apply = function () {
    angular.forEach($scope.screenMap, function (value, key) {
        var obj = {
            "ID" : value.scrn_id,
            "Read" : value.Read,
            "Write" :  value.Write
        };
        $scope.details.push(obj);
    });
    console.log($scope.details);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
       angular.forEach($scope.screenMap, function (value, key) {

            $scope.details.push({
              "ID": value.scrn_id,
              "Read": value.Read,
              "Write", value.Write
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your pushing 3 times in a loop that too two objects at a time. Dont use commas to insert key value pair(object name : value)
javascript Object annotation is as follows
var x = {"nameofthe Object1":object value1,
         "nameofthe Object2":object value2
        }
3*2*3 = 18 and these are single entries.

create a javascript object and push into the $scope.details

```
    $scope.details = [];
    $scope.apply = function () {
        angular.forEach($scope.screenMap, function (value, key) {
            //$scope.details.push(value.scrn_id, value.Read, value.Write);
            $scope.details.push({"ID": value.scrn_id,
                                 "Read": value.Read,
                                 "Write": value.Write});
        });
        console.log($scope.details);
    }
```